# Can python-constraint work with float constraints?

Tags: python, floating-point, constraints, algebra, fractions

I'm trying to learn the `constraint` module based on Google found examples, and looking at the sources.
However, if I try to solve for a *float* value, seems I'm doing something wrong.

E.g., say I wish to solve: `7x+3y=10 ; 10x-20y=10`
The solution is: `x = -1` and `y = 17/3`

Alas, solving with the `constraint` module produces an empty list solution:

```
$ cat tmp.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
7x+3y=10 ; 10x-20y=10 
"""
from constraint import Problem
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("x", [-2,-1,0,1,2])
problem.addVariable("y", [-1,1,17/3])

problem.addConstraint(lambda x, y: 7*x + 3*y == 10)
problem.addConstraint(lambda x, y: 10*x - 20*y == 10)

print problem.getSolutions()
```

with output:

```
$ python tmp.py
[]
```

1. **Is documentation available for the `constraint` module?**
2. **Can `constraint` work with *float* constraints?**

Note: I'm aware that 17/3 cannot be represented accurately on a digital computer.

### EDIT 1:

I tried @Lucho's idea of using the `fractions` module: unfortunately - it doesn't solve the issue.

```
$ cat tmp.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
7x+3y=10 ; 10x-20y=10 
"""
from constraint import Problem
from fractions import Fraction

frac = Fraction(17, 3)

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("x", [-2,-1,0,1,2])
#problem.addVariable("y", [-1,1,17/3])
problem.addVariable("y", [-1,1,frac])

problem.addConstraint(lambda x, y: 7*x + 3*y == 10)
problem.addConstraint(lambda x, y: 10*x - 20*y == 10)

print problem.getSolutions()

$ python tmp.py 
[]

$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this module before, but my guess is try using the [Fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module to represent `17/3`.

`from fractions import Fraction
 Fraction(17, 3)`

The documentation I have found is http://labix.org/doc/constraint/ but it says nothing about this particular case.

Comment: Thanks @Lucho. See my answer in `EDIT 1` of OP.